# Broadleaf admin dont update page

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

my broadleaf admin is no updating any change on page content that I make, the inmmediatly deploy always complete succesful, but for some reason is caching the old page, If I clean app´s cache the change is updating and I can see my change and also if deploy manually It clean chache and the change is displaying.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Broadleaf uses SOLR indexing for products which runs after every 60 minutes by default. So if you make some changes and even if you don't clean your cache, the changes will be reflected after 60 minutes by default. 
If you want to apply the changes quicker for your testing, you can change that by reducing the time specified in the property

```
solr.index.repeat.interval=
```

in common.properties of site resources.

Comment: It was for another thing, Broadleaf use a BLC_PAGE_TMPLT table to set a languege to the templates, you should use "en" or "en_US" to make possible to clean the cache after page, contenten items, or redirects updates.